# Proving limits without limit theorems

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have to prove the following limit without using any limit theorems. I can only do so by using the Archimedean Proprety and the definition of a limit.

I have to prove:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2 - 2}{3n^2 + 1} = \frac13$$

Comment: Are you allowed to use Limit Laws, so for example; the limit of the product is equal to the product of the limits?

Comment: @CharleyScotford I believe so. How would I do it either way?

Comment: I'll put it in an answer, give me a second

Comment: I would assume "only Archimedean property and definition of a limit" means no use of the Limit Laws. A good first step is to write down what you know: what is the Archimedean property, what is the definition of a limit as $n$ goes to infinity?

Answer (score 3):

The following calculation may be helpful:

$$\left|\frac{n^2-2}{3n^2+1}-\frac13\right| = \left|\frac{(3n^2-6)-(3n^2+1)}{3(3n^2+1)}\right| = \frac73\left(\frac1{3n^2+1}\right)$$

Can you argue that $3n^2+1$ gets large as $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 3):

For $\epsilon >0$ sufficiently small $$\left|\dfrac{n^2-2}{3n^2+1}-\frac{1}{3}\right|<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow \left|\dfrac{-7}{9n^2+3}\right|<\epsilon $$ $$ \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{7}{9n^2+3}<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow \frac{7}{\epsilon}-3<9n^2\Leftrightarrow \frac{7-3\epsilon}{9\epsilon}<n^2\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{\frac{7-3\epsilon}{9\epsilon}}<n$$ That is, for every $\epsilon >0$ sufficiently small if we choose $$n_0=\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{7-3\epsilon}{9\epsilon}}\right\rfloor +1$$ then $$\left|\dfrac{n^2-2}{3n^2+1}-\frac{1}{3}\right|<\epsilon $$ if $n\ge n_0$ so, $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\dfrac{n^2-2}{3n^2+1}=\dfrac{1}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll help get you started. You want to show that N>n => |(n^2 - 2)/(3n^2 + 1) -1/3| < epsilon. (Definition of convergence of a sequence).

First, get a common denominator. 
|-7/(9n^2+3)|< epsilon

Then you're gonna want to solve for n in terms of epsilon and set N equal to the value you get for n.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so lets look at the problem:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^2 -2}{3n^2 +1}.$$

The key here is to do a bit of algebra - on that basis, remove a factor of $n^2$ on the top and bottom:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^2\big(1-\frac{2}{n^2}\big)}{n^2\big(3 +\frac{1}{n^2}\big)} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\big(1-\frac{2}{n^2}\big)}{\big(3 +\frac{1}{n^2}\big)}.$$

Now we can apply the limit laws step by step (I don't know how familiar you are with this, so I'll go slowly), the first is that we can pass the limit over the fraction:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\big(1-\frac{2}{n^2}\big)}{\big(3 +\frac{1}{n^2}\big)} = \frac{\lim_{n\to \infty} \big(1-\frac{2}{n^2}\big)}{\lim_{n\to \infty} \big(3 +\frac{1}{n^2}\big)}.$$

Then we can pass the limit through the brackets (baring in mind that the limit of a constant is just the constant):

$$\frac{\big(1-\lim_{n\to \infty} \big[ \frac{2}{n^2}\big]\big)}{ \big(3 +\lim_{n\to \infty}\big[ \frac{1}{n^2}\big]\big)}.$$

Knowing now that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = 0$ we have that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^2 -2}{3n^2 +1} = \frac{1-0}{3+0} = \frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: When we "pass the limit over the fraction", aren't we using limit theorems? Namely, that the limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits?

Comment: I did ask in the comments and the OP said they assumed it was okay to use limit laws. Limit theorems is kind of an ambiguous phrase really since it could refer to any number of theorems relating to limits such as L'Hôpital's rule or alike. They did ask how to do it either way so I left it here for reference if they wanted it :)

Comment: That's fair enough. It's good to have both approaches explicated, for the benefit of future readers as well as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The Archimedean Property can be used to show that

$\tag 1 \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = 0$

It is easy to show that

$\tag 2\frac{n^2 - 2}{3n^2 + 1} \lt \frac{1}{3} \text{ for all } n \ge 0$

The following statements are all equivalent for any $0 \lt \varepsilon \lt \frac{7}{3}$ when $n \gt 0$:

$\tag 3 \frac{1}{3} - \varepsilon \lt \frac{n^2 - 2}{3n^2 + 1}$

$\tag , n^2 + \frac{1}{3} - 3 n^2 \varepsilon  - \varepsilon \lt n^2 - 2$

$\tag , \frac{7}{3}  - \varepsilon \lt 3 n^2 \varepsilon$

$\tag 4 \frac{1}{n^2}  \lt \frac{3 \varepsilon}{\frac{7}{3}  - \varepsilon}$

By (1) we can find an $N$ so that (4) is true when $n \ge N$. But then both (2) and (3) show that

$\tag 5 \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2 - 2}{3n^2 + 1} = \frac13$